# Getting all the history of transactions in hyperledger-composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

The hyperledger composer provides a Historian API to query for history of transactions, but the information is limited. I need to see the kind of asset that were created, along with their identifier. But the record info does not show this, it just says the asset was created.

```
 {
    "$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord",
    "transactionId": "23a722c7022674e6c1ea13697845efb7a3b3453063c7eed01671dd92ad959354",
    "transactionType": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset",
    "transactionInvoked": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset#23a722c7022674e6c1ea13697845efb7a3b3453063c7eed01671dd92ad959354",
    "participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#restadmin",
    "identityUsed": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#132bf760b9f7d58d4949d3a40825a62cec31bb4d206a664a9960b470c22b5cab",
    "eventsEmitted": [],
    "transactionTimestamp": "2018-06-02T14:11:22.084Z"
  }
```

How can I fetch the info?

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to item 6 in the table shown below:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--historian-queries---common-asks

Furthermore, you can use the loopback filters in the REST APIs to resolve the relationships to assets such as `{"where":{"commodity":"resource:org.acme.biznet.Commodity#ABC"}, "include":"resolve"}` on the transaction class (in this case I have a `Trade` transaction class, from the 'trading-network' Composer sample network) - to resolve the detail on the transaction invoked.